# Loading listview using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have the following case to solve:
I want to populate my listview (MainActivity.java) when splash screen (SplashScreenActivity.java) is displayed to the user. I would like to use AsyncTask to perform this action but i don't know exactly how to use it in this case:

SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);



    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);


        }
    }, 1500);

}
```

MainActivity.java is just a listview which shows data using JSON.

Comment: Look for `AsyncTask` tutorials .

Comment: Generally speaking, if you don't know how to start with something, you should **look for a tutorial**. StackOverflow is *not* a tutorials site. It is a Q&A site <- very different. Please visit [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0):

Dont listen to this comments.

You need to open `MainActivity` before `SplashActivity`, in `MainActivity` you need to fetch the data from the server and load the list, while it is fetching you open the `SplashActivity` and calls the same `PostDelayed` method that you are using but when it runs just calls `finish();` and it will be back to `MainActivity` hopefully loaded.

Be aware that you are assuming that the internet connection of the user is fast enough to load the data in `1500` miliseconds, the ideal of this situation is using a Event based application, look for [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to achieve that.